# Deciding to apply interaction to my model

Tags: r, anova, inference

I'm analyzing a data set with 2 factors: location and day, and a response variable: time of a given event.

My question is should I suppose interaction between factors?. As domain knowledge I've got that probably there is not interaction, and my teachers always said that if simplest model can explain variability I shouldn't make it more complex. But in the other hand, I think that there is still possible there is interaction between those factors so I'm tempted to test it.

When I test the model:
$$y_{ijk} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{location}_j + \beta_2 \text{day}_k + \epsilon_{ijk},$$
Both factors are significant, and when I test the model: 
$$y_{ijk} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{location}_j + \beta_2 \text{day}_k + \epsilon_{ijk} + \beta_3(\text{location}\cdot\text{day})_{jk} + \epsilon_{ijk},$$
The interaction is significant too, so I'm confused and don't know which model approaches the reality better.

What would you do? Would choose the simplest model or would apply the interaction to it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your notation is very unusual.  You would usually have subscripts on the X, and all the coefs would be B, with subscripts.

Comment: Thank you for your considerations. I've written the formal models.

Comment: The names 'location' and 'day' are highly suggestive of dependency. Are you sure these are independent measures?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Im trying to identify if there is some correlation between the latency time in a computer procedure and location or time to be able to identify if the error was generated some concrete day or in some concrete place. The hypothesis are "the main server may have failed and concrete days latency times grow" or "local servers and/or other failures happen at concrete locations".

Answer (score 1):

If there had been no strong reason to test for the interaction then, particularly in a model with many predictors when there might be dozens of interaction terms, many people would not have tested for it. Since you have and found an interaction you cannot really ignore it. You cannot put the toothpaste back in the tube.

The next step depends on what the shape of the interaction is. If it is that location has the same direction of effect every day but just some days more than others then it is relatively simple to report that. If at the other extreme the pattern is very strange and nobody can think of a plausible explanation then I would suggest reporting the fact of the interaction but suggest it may just be a Type I error.

It is perhaps worth mentioning that in general tests for interaction are less precise than for main effects although that fact is not directly relevant here.

Comment: About your last paragraph, do you mean a significance test for the coefficient of an interaction term? Is there anything else to this imprecision other than having more parameters to estimate?

Comment: @FransRodenburg my understanding is that the location*day means will be less stably estimated. The within SOS will be the same (assuming this is a location by day ANOVA.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I am thinking is: I should have not tested it (maybe because there is no reason to think they interact at first look, maybe because my simpler model was significant enough to explain the reality), but when I did, just the act of doing it makes the newer more complex model "correct"?. Btw, I think that for the interaction I can give the explanation of: "Some days the latency grow. In some locations the latencies are higher because of particular conditions of that locations. Some days, some locations latencies are higher because communication errors, storms, etc"